# Is there any way I can get the node console to tell me all available methods attached to an object?

Tags: node.js

For example, if I wanted to know all the methods and properties, methods and events available on the base http class, I could type something like `http()?` and it would return

```
http.createServer([requestListener])
http.createClient([port], [host])
```

Comment: why would you want this over reading the documentation? you're just going to get a lot of noise and internal apis. you're probably better off reading the source code.

Comment: Its great when you're in the console to have this kind of info. Maybe I'm just to used to Ruby.

I don't see what's noisey about a list of methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any of the `require` modules like `http`, just enter the name at the console prompt:

```
> http
```

You get a little tidier presentation if you enter `http.` at the prompt and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Both will tell you names of the available functions, but not their parameters.  You need to check the docs for that.